# (TSQL) How do I divide a row into 4 distinct rows, all the records need to remain the same except for the subject record

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

Right now this is what the query returns.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAgoc.png

Its one row with 4 columns.

I need it to return 4 rows with gift amount divided by four as shown below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDSfa.png

There are several thousand rows that each need its own 4 rows.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Reasons not to use images are [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/92546). What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea is to essentially duplicate the row four times, and then divide the gift card amount in each one by four. We can conveniently do this by creating a small table with the number `4` in four rows:

```
-- ---------
-- TEST DATA
-- ---------
drop table if exists #temp, #numbers

create table #temp (
    Company_Code int, Company_Number int,
    Company_Value int, Gift_Amount int)

create table #numbers (
    [value] decimal(9,3))

insert into #temp 
    values (11520,3520,1150,1250)

insert into #numbers 
    values (4),(4),(4),(4)

-- ---------
-- THE QUERY
-- ---------
select 
    #temp.*, 
    #temp.Gift_Amount / #numbers.[value] as New_Gift_Amount
    from #temp
    cross join #numbers
```

Result:

| Company_Code | Company_Number | Company_Value | Gift_Amount | New_Gift_Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11520 | 3520 | 1150 | 1250 | 312.5000000000 |
| 11520 | 3520 | 1150 | 1250 | 312.5000000000 |
| 11520 | 3520 | 1150 | 1250 | 312.5000000000 |
| 11520 | 3520 | 1150 | 1250 | 312.5000000000 |